# MySQL MVCC (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, isolation-level

The question is about the behavior of simultaneous SELECT and UPDATE in MySQL InnoDB table:

We have a relatively large table which we periodically scan reading several fields including a field named, say, `LastUpdate`. During the scan we update previously scanned rows. Updates are batched and performed in a background thread - using a different connection. It is important to note that we update rows that *have already been read*.

Three questions:

1. Will InnoDB will save previous versions of the updated rows since the SELECT is still in progress?
2. Would using READ-UNCOMMITTED for the SELECT help?
3. How can I confirm that InnoDB saves or does not save previous versions of the modified rows in its redo-log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the issue, and write code that won't get in trouble:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT id ... LIMIT 20; -- get list of _possible_ candidates for action
COMMIT;
**
foreach $candidate
    BEGIN;
    SELECT ..., is_candidate WHERE id = $candidate FOR UPDATE;
    if still a candidate
        process it
        UPDATE ...;
    COMMIT;
```

If someone slips in, say, at `**`, the check later will prevent double-processing.  Furthermore, the second BEGIN..COMMIT prevents anyone from slipping in.

`FOR UPDATE` "locks" the row; this is important.

The advantage of processing this way is that the transactions are *quick*, thereby minimizing impact on everything else.

Comment: Not sure I understand the answer. The SELECT statement in my case potentially returns a *lot* of rows (100,000 or more). The question was whether I can somehow tell MySQL I have finished processing the first 1000 rows and there is no need to keep the old versions of these rows while they are updated.

Comment: Probably the only way is to break it into clumps yourself.

Comment: Well, using LIMIT/OFFSET is very inefficient and using a server fetch cursor forces MySQL to create a temporary table -- which again means copying all the data. Perhaps partitioning by the primary key would work best. Thanks!

Comment: `OFFSET` is terribly inefficient; `PARTITIONing` won't help.  Walking through table by the PK is a good way to do it.  [More on chunking](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).